# How to add canvas xaml resource in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have downloaded this pack : http://modernuiicons.com/ and I'm trying to use the xaml icons.

I have added a xaml file to my solution with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_check" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
<Path Width="37.9998" Height="31.6665" Canvas.Left="19.0001" Canvas.Top="22.1668" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 23.7501,33.25L 34.8334,44.3333L 52.2499,22.1668L 56.9999,26.9168L 34.8334,53.8333L 19.0001,38L 23.7501,33.25 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

Now, how do I reference this canvas to my usercontrol?

Usercontrol

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="UserControlSolution.UserControlButton"
x:Name="UserControl"
Height="50" Background="#FF2F2F2F" BorderBrush="#FF919191">


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="230" Height="50"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="NameLabel" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FFE5E5E5" Height="34" Width="149" Text="Onthaal Telefoon" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16.5" Width="17.789" Margin="0,15,24.5,0">
        // Here I want to reference the canvas
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I can copy the content of the canvas offcourse but there must be another solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the `Canvas` and `Path` as a resource on the page or in the App.xaml or whatever, remember to set `x:Key`. Then use a `ContentControl` to reference the resource.

```
<!-- In Resources, either on the Page or App.xaml for app-wide reuse -->
<Canvas x:Key="TickCanvas" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_check" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="37.9998" Height="31.6665" Canvas.Left="19.0001" Canvas.Top="22.1668" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 23.7501,33.25L 34.8334,44.3333L 52.2499,22.1668L 56.9999,26.9168L 34.8334,53.8333L 19.0001,38L 23.7501,33.25 Z "/>
</Canvas

<!-- On your page, or somewhere -->
<ViewBox>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource TickCanvas}" />
</ViewBox>
```

As proof it works, I was able to see its a tick!

Just a side note, I often take just the path data, the mini-markup and save that as a string resource. Then using a `Path` I reference the markup resource via `Data={StaticResource TickPath}` that way I can resize the vector using the `Height` and `Width` on the `Path` itself or let it expand and shrink by its parent by setting `Stretch="Uniform"`. Saves the overhead of the `Viewbox`.

```
<!-- In App.xaml for app-wide reuse -->
<x:String x:Key="TickPath">F1 M 23.7501,33.25L 34.8334,44.3333L 52.2499,22.1668L 56.9999,26.9168L 34.8334,53.8333L 19.0001,38L 23.7501,33.25 Z </x:String>

<!-- On page, template or wherever -->
<Path Data="{StaticResource TickPath} />
```

This technique may not work in this instance as there's a clip geometry there. But for simple vectors its fine, I have hand drawn typefaces (that can't be embedded as fonts) stored as markup in files, I then load them in at runtime - `Data={Binding PathData}` works just as well.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. I have to copy the content of the canvas resource to my app resources and add a key to it and then reference it in the contentcontrol?

Answer (score 1):

A variation based on Luke's answer allowing a color to be specified down to the path.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="TickIcon">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="appbar_check" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                        <Path Width="37.9998" Height="31.6665" Canvas.Left="19.0001" Canvas.Top="22.1668" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" Data="F1 M 23.7501,33.25L 34.8334,44.3333L 52.2499,22.1668L 56.9999,26.9168L 34.8334,53.8333L 19.0001,38L 23.7501,33.25 Z "/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and

```
<Button Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <WrapPanel>
        <ContentControl Foreground="AliceBlue" Style="{StaticResource TickIcon}" Width="20" />
        <TextBlock>Connect</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
</Button>
```